# spring MVC extended controllers don't resolve

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, spring-annotations

I have the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController extends BaseHtmlController{

    @Autowired
    protected DeviceCustomerMap deviceCustomerMap;

    @Autowired
    protected CustomerDao customerDao;

    String layout = "template/admin";

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("meta", meta);
        String view = "login";
        return view;
    }


}


public class AdminCustomerController extends AdminController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/customer/mapping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customerMapping(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(required=false) boolean refresh) throws Exception {
        if (refresh){
            deviceCustomerMap.initCustomerUrlMap();
        }
        model.addAttribute("meta", meta);
        model.addAttribute("view", "customer/mapping");
        model.addAttribute("customers", deviceCustomerMap.getCustomerMap());
        return layout;
    }
}
```

However, the extended controller doesn't resolve the requests, but when they're in the base controller, they're resolved just fine, I've poked around several threads but couldn't find a solution, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the problem that you are able to get a response when executing a request to the `/admin/login` resource, but not to `/admin/customer/mapping` resource, unless you move the `customerMapping()` method to the `AdminController` class?

The solution is to annotate the `AdminCustomerController` class with the `@Controller` annotation. Without a [stereotype](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) annotation (and appropriate component scanning), Spring will not recognise the class as a Spring bean.

Comment: and what if I have more than 1 class which inherits from AdminController?

Comment: Every controller class needs to have its own `@Controller` annotation in order to be picked up by Spring.